# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in

Tags: server, githooks, phar

When I deploy my commits via Git to the server, it runs a git hook that has the line

```
test -f composer.phar && ./composer.phar self-update || curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php;
```

That generates the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in .../composer.phar on line 23
```

This is line 23 from composer.phar:

```
Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar');
```

I did search other questions with the same problem and checked these things:

- git hook's script already has permission to be executed
- I can execute `./composer.phar` without error when logged in server and inside the same folder as set in the git hook's script
- PHP modules has Phar enabled, checked via `php -m`
- There is no `extension=phar.so` in php.ini, but I dont think it has to be because it's already enabled
- PHP version: PHP 5.5.3 (cli)

What else could be causing this?

Comment: I know it's been a few years, but were you running this on Cygwin by any chance?

Comment: No I wasn't, this was on a ubuntu environment. I don't have it anymore but it happened due to php configuration and the paths of stuff were in.